# Regex of path not working

Tags: regex

I need to create reg-ex for path like aaaa/bbb/ccc or aaa-bbb or aaa_bbb_ccc_ddd etc
How should I do that ?
It can contain only **alpha numeric with hyphen underscore and slash**.
Ive tried something like this which is not working

```
@"^((?:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+/?|/?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+/)+)[a-zA-Z0-9]*$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind if your path has mixed delimiters like `aaa-bbb/ccc` then you can get it done in one go reasonably easily with:

```
"^(?:[A-z0-9]+[-_\/]?)*$"
```

This will accept `aaa-bbb/ccc`, and `aaa/` but reject `aaa--bbb`. If you want to ensure that you have only one type of delimiter, then we can create one repeated block for each delimiter type:

```
"^(?:(?:[A-z0-9]+-?)*|(?:[A-z0-9]+_?)*|(?:[A-z0-9]+\/?)*)$"
```

This will still tolerate trailing delimiters, which you can get rid of that by adding another group to the end:

```
"^(?:(?:[A-z0-9]+-?)*|(?:[A-z0-9]+_?)*|(?:[A-z0-9]+\/?)*)[A-z0-9]+$"
```

If you want allow leading delimiters, just move them before the group. Also notice the extra `\s*` to allow trailing whitespace.

```
"^(?:(?:-?[A-z0-9]+)*|(?:_?[A-z0-9]+)*|(?:\/?[A-z0-9]+?)*)\s*$"
```

Not exactly easy on the eyes, but it does work (in perl at least).

Comment: Thanks Jon ,voted up! I use the last regex you provided. there is two little thing,how can I add that user can start with the symbols like /aaaa/bbbb or -aaa-bbb-ccc. and how should ignore the spacess at the end for example if user type value with and at the end add space he got errors...

Comment: There you go, I've updated the answer to include the extra details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one to match words

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]*[-/_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b
```

[image]

---

Note:

- `\w` include underscore also that why I have used `[a-zA-Z0-9]`
- remove `\b` from either end if you don't want to match word boundary

Pattern expatiation:

```
\w     A word character: [a-zA-Z_0-9]
\b     A word boundary
[abc]  a, b, or c (simple class)
```